# How to filter errors in a Bacon.js stream

Tags: bacon.js

Sometimes I want to filter out certain errors in a stream. I'd like to write something like this:

```
stream
  .filterError (error) ->
    error.type is 'foo'
```

But there is no `filterError` method.

As an alternative I thought I could use `errors().mapError` to map the errors into values, filter them, and then map them back into errors. However, I don't see a way to convert a value in a stream into an error.

```
# Filter only the errors we are interested in
errors = stream.errors()
  .mapError (error) ->
    error
  .filter (error) ->
    ...
  .mapValuesBackIntoErrors() # ?
```

The idea is that the stream in question either carries a value or an error. Both represent domain knowledge; the value means the system is in normal operation and the error means we have a domain error. Some of the domain errors are not such that we want to carry them, though, so I wish to filter them out.

Comment: do you consider this answered? the below seems strange. i can totally see where you're coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative works, of course, and you may use a combination of *map* and *mapError* to wrap normal values and errors in the style of the [Either](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-Either.html) type in Haskell. For instance

```
stream.map((value) -> { value }).mapError((error) -> { error })
```

Now your stream would output something like this:

```
{ value: 1 }
{ value: 2 }
{ error: "cannot connect to host" }
```

On the other hand, actually implementing *filterError* wouldn't be too hard. Consider implementing this yourself and making a PR.

Comment: It might be confusing to have a `filterError` that filters out errors and `mapError` that maps errors into values. `mapError :: Error -> Error` feels more correct to me.

Comment: I corrected it to "filterError" as you suggested. The mapError as is was added for a purpose, and I think it serves it well, even though you might find it confusing at first. What would be the purpose of your suggested alternative?